# What does this permission mean?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

I'm a little confused as to what this permission means. Could someone break it down for me?

`-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 38 Oct4 21:14 testfile`

And if I wanted to execute my test file I would type something like this `chmod 733 testfile`

Does this mean only john can write to the `testfile`?

Answer (score 0):

This permission means the **owner** (in this case john) has read/write permissions and the **group** and **everyone else** has only read permissions.

Check this links out for more info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-3321/6n5i4b79m/index.html
- http://www.firewall.cx/linux-knowledgebase-tutorials/introduction-to-linux.html/299-linux-file-folder-permissions.html